# how to fix mysql installation errors

Tags: mysql, installation

i'm trying to install mySQL using mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.15.0 
but it stops in this stage (see image bellow)

![My_SQL Eroor]https://ibb.co/0p72Xjf

When i click on show details this is what i have :

1: Download of package 'MySQL Server 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product MySQL Server 8.0.15

2: Download of package 'MySQL Workbench 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product MySQL Workbench 8.0.15

3: Download of package 'MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8' failed with message No valid download found for product MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8

4: Download of package 'MySQL Shell 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product MySQL Shell 8.0.15

5: Download of package 'MySQL Router 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product MySQL Router 8.0.15

6: Download of package 'Connector/ODBC 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product Connector/ODBC 8.0.15

7: Download of package 'Connector/C++ 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product Connector/C++ 8.0.15

8: Download of package 'Connector/J 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product Connector/J 8.0.15

9: Download of package 'Connector/NET 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product Connector/NET 8.0.15

10: Download of package 'Connector/Python (3.7) 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product Connector/Python (3.7) 8.0.15

11: Download of package 'MySQL Documentation 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product MySQL Documentation 8.0.15

12: Download of package 'Samples and Examples 8.0.15' failed with message No valid download found for product Samples and Examples 8.0.15

Answer (score 2):

I took same error. When I changed my internet connection(I connected another wifi network:)) the problem solved.I think your problem was in proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

Some firewalls blocks the installer connection such as Kaspersky, try to temporary disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Proxy was not allowing my installer to connect to the Internet, I used the installer having bigger size.
This installer, downloads everything with it, and does not depend upon internet later on.
Just check the size on the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before; I upgraded my installer, then tried installing MySQL, and there wasn't any error.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it in 2022, encountered the same problem, so I updated its catalog and then installed the workbench again, it will automatically update the required prerequisites such as ms visuals c++ and others and the installer will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Re-download the latest installer run it, fixes the problem